# Graph Theory Amortized Analysis

Tags: performance, python-3.x

I created some code to represent a graph. There are two functions to operate on the graph. The first which uses a list of nodes, determines if there is a key in a graph. The second which uses an adjacency matrix finds the weight of the graph given two keys. As an optimization, the first function swaps closer to the start of the list once found. Also, the second function does something similar, but operates on a 2d list.

My question is what is the amortized time and amortized space for the two functions.

Below is the code

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass 
from typing import List 
from typing import Any 

@dataclass
class Node:
    row: int 
    value: Any 

@dataclass 
class Cell:
    from_row: int 
    to_row: int 
    weight: int 
    has_edge: bool 

def find_weight(rows: int, cols: int, from_key: int, to_key: int, matrix: List[List[Cell]]) -> int:
#amortized time: ?
#amortized space: ? 
    weight =  0  
    found = False 

    row = 0
    col = 0  
    while not found and row < rows:
        while not found and col < cols:
            if matrix[row][col].from_row == from_key and matrix[row][col].to_row == to_key:
                weight = matrix[row][col].weight 
                found = True 
                break 
            col = col + 1 
        row = row + 1 

    #the app increment incrased one more time once found became False 
    row = row - 1 
    col = col - 1 

    #the app move found cell closer to start of loops for next time find weight is called 
    if row > 0 and col > 0:
        matrix[row][col], matrix[row - 1][col - 1] = matrix[row - 1][col -1], matrix[row][col]
    elif row > 0:
        matrix[row][col], matrix[row - 1][col] = matrix[row - 1][col], matrix[row][col]
    elif col > 0:
         matrix[row][col], matrix[row][col - 1] = matrix[row][col -1], matrix[row][col]
    return weight 

def test_find_weight():
    assert find_weight(1, 1, 0, 0, [[Cell(0, 0, 1, True)]]) == 1 
    assert find_weight(1, 1, 1, 0, [[Cell(0, 0, 0, False)]]) == 0 
    assert find_weight(0, 0, 1, 1, [[]]) == 0 

def has_key(rows: int, row: int, nodes: List[Node]) -> bool:
#amortized time: ? 
#amortized space: ? 
    has = False 
    found_row = 0 
    for node in nodes:
        if node.row == row:
            has = True 
            found_row = row 
            break 
    
    #the app moved node closer to start of loop for next time has key is called 
    if has and found_row > 0:
        nodes[found_row], nodes[found_row - 1] = nodes[found_row - 1], nodes[found_row]

    return has 


def test_has_key():
    assert has_key(2, 1, [Node(0, "a"), Node(1, "b")]) == True
    assert has_key(2, 2, [Node(0, "a"), Node(1, "b")]) == False 
    assert has_key(2, 1, [Node(1, "b"), Node(0, "a")]) == True 


def tests():
    test_has_key()
    test_find_weight()  
    print("Tests done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests()
```

Comment: Are you looking for suggestions on how to improve the code? If you are strictly asking about analyzing the time and space complexity of the code, then it's [not really an appropriate question for Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8373).

Comment: Both actually. First, I am looking for a way to analyze performance (I am unsure how to do this step). Second, I am looking for ways to improve maintainability.